# Using PHP 'scandir' on external domain

Tags: php, cross-domain, scandir

I don't like asking for help directly. Usually I can find the answer by looking at similar questions, however this has me stumped!

I've been asked to figure out a basic CCTV system using FOSCAM cameras, a Raspberry Pi running nginx and some other magic. I managed all of these things perfectly and enabled the directory to be able to go directly to it, however as I don't have PHP installed on every node (36 nodes currently) and i would rather run this front-end via another host.

It's a little confusing but basically all of my nodes have a ddns which i navigate to like so: "http://myddnsdomain.net" which plops me in a directory listing days and then hours which contain image files. This all works fine. What I want to do is - on another domain, have a page which displays the latest image uploaded from the directory http://myddnsdomain.net/directory/

Please see my code below. The problem is that scandir is not working. I get no errors, it's just blank.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Image Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Latest Image from North Harrow</p>'; ?> 

<?php

global $path;
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$dfol = date("d-m-y/H:00");
$dir = "http://sampi24.ddns.net/$dfol/";
$files = scandir($dir, 1); // read directory backkwards
$picture = $files[0]; // get last picture file name
$path = "http://sampi24.ddns.net/$dfol/$picture";

?>

<a href="<?php global $path;echo $path; ?>">
<img class="alignnone size-large" alt="Last picture" src="<?php global 
$path;echo $path; ?>" width="1600" height="1200" /></a>

 </body>
</html>
```

Also I did try it at the base directory of sampi24.ddns.net but it's still blank.

Any light which can be shed on this would be greatly appreciated! I'm a bit of a php novice.

Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: You're using a stand-in domain in your explanation but your code example seems to have the real domain listed. Be careful posting real information.

Comment: I'm aware. I decided there was really nothing much that is considered as private data. It's just a small cctv camera in a small bakery. Thank you for letting me know though! I thought leaving it in would help with figuring out a solution.

Comment: Are you running from the command line, or the browser? If the browser are you getting a server error (HTTP status code 40* or 50*) in developer tools?

Comment: I'm running via browser - the only logs I get are:                                  GET 
http://conceptual-designs.co.uk/wenzels/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 745ms]
reflow: 0.43ms
reflow: 0.68ms
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. wenzels
GET 
http://sampi24.ddns.net/25-05-16/15:00/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1106ms]
reflow: 0.36ms
reflow: 0.1ms

Comment: My webstack isn't using PHP these days (which makes testing harder), but when I run from the command line (OSX and Fedora) I'm seeing scandir has an inappropriate ioctl. Have you been able to confirm that scandir works at all with your stack? I saw another question that mentioned that scandir may not be enabled by default in PHP 5.5+

Comment: Hi there. Scandir is definitely enabled on the server running the php script. Out of curiosity I tried it with a local directory "." and it did list the index file and a few other files which are located within. It seems to be some kind of issue with the fact I'm trying to use an external domain. I can see this is of course an issue on domains which don't allow directory listings but I have it set up to allow such a thing. Strange indeed.

Comment: I'm going to have to let this drop for now. But one thing I just tried was running Wireshark and running the script. PHP never issues a command that leaves the machine. I'd have a look at PHP's settings and see if anything looks suggestive there. Good luck.

Comment: @RegularlyScheduledProgramming I appreciate your help with this. Thank you for looking into this for me. I will do as suggested and if I figure it out I will let people know!

Comment: It seems that a log file is being created which contains the following:                                                                                                  PHP Warning:  scandir(http://sampi24.ddns.net/25-05-16/17:00/) [<a href='function.scandir'>function.scandir</a>]: failed to open dir: not implemented in /home/ryan/public_html/wenzels/index.php on line 18
[25-May-2016 17:03:14 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  scandir() [<a href='function.scandir'>function.scandir</a>]: (errno 1): Operation not permitted in /home/ryan/public_html/wenzels/index.php on line 18